# Vuetify - fixed v-toolbar-title within a v-navigation-drawer?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to have a fixed `<v-toolbar-title>` from within a `<v-navigation-drawer>`?

```
<v-card class="d-inline-block elevation-12">
    <v-navigation-drawer hide-overlay permanent stateless height="440" value="true">
        <v-toolbar color="white" flat>
           <v-toolbar-title>Name</v-toolbar-title>
```

My goal is to be able to scroll within the drawer, but have the toolbar remain at the top, but the `inverted-scroll` and `fixed` props aren't working in the floating navigation drawer.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdqjwX?editors=1000

Answer (score 2):

You can use prepend slot

```
<v-navigation-drawer>
    <template v-slot:prepend>
        your title
    </template>
    
    <template v-slot:append>
        your footer
    </template>
</v-navigation-drawer>
```